# Line Number for all non-blank lines?

Tags: text-processing, cat, nl

Kind of amused here, I'm trying to pass the [prereqs](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud219/lessons/972928869/concepts/9977987120923) to get into the [Udacity Course on High Performance Computer Architecture by  Georgia Institute of Technology](https://www.udacity.com/course/high-performance-computer-architecture--ud007) For the life of me I can't figure out what they want,

Question reads,

> To list the contents of a file, with line numbers for non-blank line shown use the command with an option: ________ ___ filename.

I've tried `nl`. It didn't work. Most bizarre question ever.

[image: Question]

Comment: Not sure we need an image of the textual question, given that you've reproduced the question in text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `cat` also has that option,

> **`-b`, `--number-nonblank`** number nonempty output lines, overrides `-n`

So now I guess `cat -b` and `nl` are the same. Joys!

```
$ cat -b ./foo.py 
     1  a = 5
     2  a = a + 1

     3  print "foobarbaz" + str(a);

$ nl ./foo.py 
     1  a = 5
     2  a = a + 1

     3  print "foobarbaz" + str(a);
```

Comment: wtf. this seems so esoteric that I can't imagine why `cat` would bother implementing such a feature (especially since `nl` and `cat` are both part of coreutils). And it makes me think the authors of that question deliberately went looking for something nobody would know.

Answer (score 9):

While `cat`'s numbering is not POSIX, `nl` is, and POSIX also defines the numbering styles that `nl` uses:

```
−b type  Specify which logical page  body  lines  shall  be  numbered.
         Recognized types and their meaning are:

         a       Number all lines.

         t       Number only non-empty lines.

         n       No line numbering.

         pstring Number  only  lines  that  contain  the basic regular
                 expression specified in string.

         The default type for logical page body shall be t (text lines
         numbered).
```

So, even though it is the default:

```
nl -bt filename
```

Answer (score 0):

'nl' offers more formatting options than 'cat -b.'

Punctuation such as periods "." or any other character can follow the line number, and varying amounts of white space may also be added with the '-s' option.

Number only non-empty lines:

```
$ echo -e "one\ntwo\nthree\n\n\nfour\n\nfive\nsix\nseven\n\neight\n\n\n\nnine\nten\n"|nl -bt -s\.\  -
 1. one
 2. two
 3. three


 4. four

 5. five
 6. six
 7. seven

 8. eight



 9. nine
10. ten
```

More whitespace between the line number and the line:

```
$ echo -e "one\ntwo\nthree\n\n\nfour\n\nfive\nsix\nseven\n\neight\n\n\n\nnine\nten\n"|nl -bt -s\.\ \ \ \ \ \  -
 1.      one
 2.      two
 3.      three


 4.      four

 5.      five
 6.      six
 7.      seven

 8.      eight



 9.      nine
10.      ten
```

Two asterisks after the line number:

```
$ echo -e "one\ntwo\nthree\n\n\nfour\n\nfive\nsix\n\n"|nl -bt -s**\ \ \ \ \ \ \  -
 1**       one
 2**       two
 3**       three


 4**       four

 5**       five
 6**       six
```

Some characters like parentheses must be escaped from the shell with backslashes:

```
$ echo -e "one\ntwo\nthree\n\n\nfour\n\nfive\nsix\n\n"|nl -bt -s\(\(\ \ \ \ \ \ \  -
 1((       one
 2((       two
 3((       three


 4((       four

 5((       five
 6((       six
```