# head not returning n lines

Tags: linux, command-line, command, head, nl

When I run the command `head -n 445 /etc/snort/snort.conf | nl` I expect lines 1-445 to be returned. However, only up to line 371 is returned:

```
[snip]
370 preprocessor dcerpc2_server: default, policy WinXP, \
371     detect [smb [139, 445], tcp 35, udp 135, rpc-over-http-server 593], \
```

What is happening?

Comment: How long is the file?

Comment: Blank lines -- unnumbered?

Comment: `nl -ba` if you want it to number empty lines.

Comment: That's it! Blank lines.

Comment: Consider `|wc -l` as an alternative for counting lines...

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/523242/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/438408/117549

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nl` utility does not number blank lines by default (and you have blank lines in the input file).

Comment: See also `printf '%s\n' {a..f} '\:\:' {g..l} | nl -ba`. `nl` expects an input in a very specific format, it can't be used to number arbitrary text. Even the `nl -ba -d $'\n'` which works with some `nl` implementations doesn't work on some (like on NetBSD). See also https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.unix.shell/cxM02TRRFPg/JpaD5LzlBQAJ

Comment: Would my `|wc -l` comment on the Q be appropriate to add, Stéphane?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the command you should run:

```
nl -ba ./etc/snort/snort.conf | grep output
```

And then find the actual line that "output" is on (for me, it was 529). Once you have the line number, type in this command:

```
nl -ba ./etc/snort/snort.conf | tail -n+523 | head -n
```

The "-n+523" for you will be replaced with "-n+<Your line number minus 6>". If you don't want the lines numbered in the output, omit the "nl -ba " in front of the directory for snort.conf